# How to define list structure so XmlSerializer understands it

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization, .net-4.5

I'm working on deserializing XML I get from web service. Here is how object looks:

```
[Serializable]
public class DocketData
{

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "PolicyList")]
    public List<PolicyItem> PolicyList { get; set; }
}
```

Here is PolicyItem:

```
[Serializable]
    public class PolicyItem
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "companyName")]
        public string CompanyName { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "attnToName")]
        public string AttnToName { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "address")]
        public string Address { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "city")]
        public string City { get; set; }
```

Here is XML:

```
<DocketData>

      <PolicyList>
        <PolicyItem>
          <companyName>CRUM &MPANY</companyName>
          <attnToName>TO REPORT00</attnToName>
          <address>305 AVE.</address>
```

When I deserialize using Xml serializer it seems to properly get 1 item of PolicyItem but it won't deserialize it's properties

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change

```
[XmlElement(ElementName = "PolicyList")]
```

to

```
[XmlArray(ElementName = "PolicyList")]
```

*BTW: You don't need those `[Serializable]` attributes*

Comment: Thanks for "Serializable" tip!